# Parse object try/catch exception error

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I am trying to get a list of values from parse.com for a specific object, however i seem to be struggling with one error that keeps coming up on my screen which doesn't seem to be wrong, unless it is related to some other issue that i may have missed. i have initialised my aF variable as List aF; as you cannot see it in this class. the error i am getting is on aF = query.find() where it says unhandled exceptions,

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "UploadedFiles" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("UploadedFiles");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

        try {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            aF = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
```

I also tried to implement an if statement exception rule, but it also gives me errors in which i thought i shouldn't use it, as i cannot implement a return statement with this case.

```
public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                aF = query.find()
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

**EDIT**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "UploadedFiles" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("UploadedFiles");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                try {
                    aF = query.find();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        return null;
    }
```

Thank you for all answers, I am getting now a new error saying that variable query is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. does that mean i have to set it as a return statement ?

Comment: i don't have an error log yet, i just got an error on the editor which means i can't compile

Comment: I get this two errors when i try to compile and run Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(201, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: Can you just check if the method or class is closed properly with curly braces { }

Comment: yes that was the cause of the first error as i missed one while editing. thank you, now i'm getting a different one i will post it in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use like this.

Use callback `FindCallback`

> Retrieves a list of `ParseObjects` that satisfy this query from the
>   source in a background thread.

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have implemented  this method and started getting a new error. The main error i'm getting is with the aF = query.find();

Comment: why are you use same query inside `done` . make new object if needed

Comment: I manage to get the errors out if i remove aF = query.find() but i don't know why is the error there. how do I implement your method with the query ? thank you for your response but i'm only learning through online research.

Comment: b'coz u are accessing non-final object in anonymous class named `FindCallback`. you have to declare as final

Comment: Correct I have made the changes it seems to be working now with different error, if you have more time you can help me with it

Comment: anytime but comes after research.!